# Solution of $Ax = x$ where $A$ is a companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, companion-matrices

I am looking for conditions under which the only solution to the equation $Ax = x$, where the matrix $A$ is a companion matrix

\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

is $x = 0$. I believe this can be proved by rewriting the equation as $(A - I) x = 0$ and investigating the null space of $A - I$ (for instance through its rank), but I am not available to find satisfying conditions, since the convenient properties of $A$ which follow from being a companion matrix seem to me to disappear when I subtract the identity matrix.

My guess would be that is should be possible to state somewhat simple conditions directly in terms of the coefficients $(a_0, \dots, a_{n-1})$, or in terms of solutions to the polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + x^n$ (from which the matrix $A$ originates). Either would be fine by me.

Comment: You should simply take $x = (x_1,\ldots, x_n)'$ and try writing out the whole set of equations. It should be very easy.

Comment: The charpoly having factor of $(x-1)^k$, $k\ge 1$, is equivalent to the matrix having eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: @TonyPizza That makes sense. I guess what you're pointing towards is that the first $n-1$ rows imply $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n$, meaning the equation corresponding to the last row can be rewritten as $a_0 x_1 + a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_{n-1} x_1 = x_1$. Then $x=0$ is the unique solution to the equation as long as $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i \neq 1$. Am I missing something deeper here?

Comment: That's right. I don't see anything missing.